# Splash Screen doesn't display in iPhone 6s Plus

Tags: ios, iphone-6-plus

Added every device resolution/size splash screens in project with proper naming, But splash screen doesn't display in "iPhone6sPlus" although it display in "iPhone6Plus"

Comment: make sure you are using .png file for splash screen

Comment: Yes, I use .png images for splash and for others ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following dimensions

For iPhone 6:

750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait

1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape

For iPhone 6 Plus:

1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait

2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape

or check the following link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Answer (score 0):

I find it out. It's a bug in Simulator. In iPhone6sPlus device it's working fine but not in iPhone6sPlus Simulator. @Abhi I added all the resolution images as I mention earlier but it's not working. It's a "iPhone6sPlus Simulator" issue.